# Django rest framework: how to fetch a foreign key based on a specific field (= not id)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here, in the following code, `TaskAppointment` is a model and have a field `state` which is a foreign key to `TaskAppointmentState`. Using Django Rest Framework, I would like to update any `TaskAppointment` and to send a `state` for update.  I have this relation that works perfectly. The only problem is that DRF filters `TaskAppointmentState` based on its `pk` (or `id`). `TaskAppointmentState` has two fields: `pk` and `state` (be careful it's not the same as the one in `TaskAppointment`). I would like to change the value `state` which is sent for update to a `TaskAppointmentState` based on `TaskAppointmentState` "`state`" field = not `id`, but `state`.

To be more precise, instead of doing `instance.status_id = state.id` in the following code, I would like to do this pseudo code instead: `instance.status_id = "SELECT id FROM TaskAppointmentState WHERE state=request.GET['state']`.

Maybe I could get rid of `TaskAppointmentStateSerializer`? If you have any working solution...

```
class TaskAppointmentStateSerializer(BaseSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TaskAppointmentState


class TaskAppointmentSerializer(BaseSerializer):

    state = TaskAppointmentStateSerializer(required=False)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        try:
            state = validated_data.pop('state')
            instance.status_id = state.id
        except KeyError:
            pass
        # ... plus any other fields you may want to update
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = TaskAppointment
        fields = ['id', 'date_start', 'date_end', 'state']
        read_only_fields = ['id', ]
```

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear maybe you can be more detailed and verbose about your problem.

Comment: Hi @rahultyagi I've updated, Is is more easy to understand?

Comment: when you make a foriegn key to TaskAppointmentState within TaskAppointment model you can use the "to_field" parameter to give an alternate field/column to make the foreign key that way your second serializer will always match state instead of id. I really don't understand your question but  I think this may solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you don't need the TaskAppointmentStateSerializer.

You can use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield)  to set a relationship based on the value of a specific field in the related model:

```
class TaskAppointmentSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    state = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='state',
                                         queryset=TaskAppointmentState.objects.all())
```

Comment: This is working! May I ask you if you know a solution to change the queryset to a dynamic queryset. Actually I need to make find an `id` based on the current state `id` **and** the new `state`, something like "`SELECT id FROM app_task_appointment_state WHERE previous_state=[current ta state] AND state = [state in the POST request]`"